# .htaccess - Rewrite all other php files to index.php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is what I currently have as my htaccess file...

```
setEnv HTTP_TARGET_PAGE %{REQUEST_FILENAME}
ErrorDocument 404 default
ErrorDocument 301 default
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

#the below line doesn't work
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} *.php
#the above line doesn't work

RewriteRule ^.*$ ./index.php
```

I'm trying to have every php file or nonexistant file request pipe through index.php for processing. All the other php files are things sometimes included in index.php (using web address).

So I may have somewhere in my index.php

```
if($my_url = "www.example.com/potato"){
    require_once("potato.php");
}
```

But I dont' want them typing in "http://www.example.com/potato.php" and getting the php directly without headers and such. My htaccess isn't working right (that one line borks it every time). But I don't want to rewrite everything because image files would then not work. How do I address it?

Comment: To Popnoodles, 3dgoo, Milap, Alex Tartan, and un-lucky...
Different question with different solution. The solution you linked to rewrites everything. I was *only* trying to rewrite .php requests and unfound files, the one you link to rewrites practically everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure I understand your requirement but I think this is what you want.

```
RewriteEngine on

#don't do anything if index.php is called directly
RewriteRule ^index\.php - [L]
#if other php file called(user typed it in), redirect to extensionless uri
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /(.+)\.php
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L]    
#if extensionless uri maps to a real php file, forward to index.php
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [OR]
#or if not a real file or directory forward to index.php
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ /index.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: That worked well, thankyou! I saw a couple lines in there I didn't understand though (such as ^ /%1? [R=302,L]), and I prefer to understand my code (and I've been trying to understand htaccess and mod_rewrite for awhile now). Any resources you'd suggest?

Comment: @liljoshu when you use a group match in a condition `/(.+)\.php` the back reference becomes `%1` which is being captured by `(.+)` So the rewrite rule will redirect with a 302 to that location. It can be difficult to understand at first, it just takes time. Honestly the whole [rewrite doc](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) is a good place to start. Then get familiar with regex and it'll come together.